# What is changed in this PDB file?

Tags: proteins, pdb

I used [a tool called reduce](https://github.com/rlabduke/reduce) to add Hydrogen bonds information to the PDB file.

I used the command:

```
$ ./reduce -NOFLIP 2GB1.pdb > 2GB1_with_H.pdb
```

The output file is supplied as follows:

- https://textdoc.co/ZiuA0tY2elnoh5VK

I haven't understood the output.

What special change was made by the tool to the `2GB1.pdb` file?

Comment: Did you read [the paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022283698924019) and maybe contact the authors (http://kinemage.biochem.duke.edu/about/) if the paper doesn't make it clear?

Comment: Are you sure its pdt format and not pdbqt ? (Didnt check , but never found it so far) :https://userguide.mdanalysis.org/1.1.1/formats/reference/pdbqt.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the 'right' answer here would be for you to use a `diff` tool of some kind (WinDiff, or just the diff command in a Unix-like environment). That would show you the exact added lines. (Although, trying this myself does not produce very clear results...)

However, I know from running `reduce` on PDB files that it's added a few things:

- The "USER MOD" lines, there's one on the first line and a large block just before the ATOM records
- The hydrogen atoms, of course, needed for correct H-bond calculations

As some commenters have pointed out, this should really be in the paper or other documentation for the tool.